# how to extract sublists of equal length from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Starting with something like:

```
lis = {a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, g}, {h, j, k}, m, n};
```

...my goal is to operate on `lis` and get:

```
{{c,d},{f,g}}
```

...in other words to extract all the sublists of lis that have two elements (regardless of those elements might be.  Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Take a look at `Cases`.

Comment: `Cases[lis, {_, _}]`. `Select[lis, Length@# == 2 &]`. `Replace[lis, Except[{_, _}] :> (## &[]), 1]`.

Comment: Do you know the length of the target sublists, i.e. length two, or do you want to find sublists of an arbitrary length that is repeated?  What would be the output for `{a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, g}, {h, j, k}, m, n, {o, p, q}}`

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses!  Mr. Wizard, output of your test case would be {{c,d},{f,g}}

Comment: `DeleteCases[Except[{_, _}]][lis]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@march has already given the answer, but neglected to write one formally. There are multiple ways to do this, but the one that makes most sense to me is this:

```
Select[lis, (Length[#]==2) &]
```

I'm going to guess that you're not familiar with some of the syntax here, so I'll break it down a bit.

`Select` is a function taking in a *list* follow by a *predicate* to be applied to elements of the list. A predicate is a function of a single argument which outputs either `True` or `False`. The `Select` method will apply the predicate to each of the elements of the list, and remove those for whom the output is `False`. Note that it doesn't alter the original list; it just outputs a new one.

Here, the *predicate* is a **pure function**: `(Length[#] == 2)&`. The `#` is replaced with the first argument that this function is applied to, so for each element `el` in the list `lis`, `Select` is checking to see if `Length[el]==2` is `True`. If it is, then it remains in the list.

We could make a function which takes in the desired sublist length and returns the appropriate *predicate*:

```
filterLength[n_]:=(Length[#]==n)&;
```

Full code:

```
filterLength[n_]:=(Length[#]==n)&;
lis    = {a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, g}, {h, j, k}, m, n};
newLis0 = Select[lis,filterLength[0]];
newLis2 = Select[lis,filterLength[2]];
newLis3 = Select[lis,filterLength[3]];
Print[newLis0]; Print[newLis2]; Print[newLis3];
```

Output:

```
{a,b,e,m,n}
{{c,d},{f,g}}
{{h,j,k}}
```

Notice that order is preserved.